# SharePlum error : "Can't get User Info List"

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to use [SharePlum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SharePlum/0.1.1) which is a Python module for SharePoint but when I try to connect to my SharePoint, SharePlum raises me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Sharpoint/sharpoint.py", line 13, in  site = Site(sharepoint_url, auth=auth)
>   File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\shareplum\shareplum.py", line 46, in **init** self.users = self.GetUsers()
>   File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\shareplum\shareplum.py", line 207, in GetUsers raise Exception("Can't get User Info List")
>   Exception: Can't get User Info List

Here is the very short code that I have written:

```
auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)  
site = Site(sharepoint_url, auth=auth)
```

This error seems to indicate bad username/password but I'm pretty sure that the one I have are correct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I found the solution for my problem, it's about the Sharepoint URL that I gave.
If we take this example : `https://www.mysharepoint.com/Your/SharePoint/DocumentLibrary`
You have to remove the last part : `/DocumentLibrary`.

**Why remove this part precisely ?**
In fact, when you go deep enough in your Sharepoint, your url will look like something like : `https://www.mysharepoint.com/Your/SharePoint/DocumentLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FYour%2FSharePoint%2DocumentLibrary%2FmyPersonnalFolder&FolderCTID=0x0120008BBC54784D92004D1E23F557873CC707&View=%7BE149526D%2DFD1B%2D4BFA%2DAA46%2D90DE0770F287%7D`

You can see that the right of the path is in `RootFolder=%2FYour%2FSharePoint%2DocumentLibrary%2Fmy%20personnal%20folder` and not in the "normal" URL anymore (if it were, it will be like that `https://www.mysharepoint.com/Your/SharePoint/DocumentLibrary/myPersonnalFolder/`).

What you have to remove is the end of the "normal" URL so in this case, `/DocumentLibrary`.

So my correct Sharepoint URL to input in SharePlum will be `https://www.mysharepoint.com/Your/SharePoint/`

I'm pretty new to Sharepoint so I'm not really sure that this I the right answer to this problem for the others persons, may someone who know Sharepoint better than me can confirm ?

Comment: bang, you should accept your own answer; it saved so much headache.  Basically, use the bare minimum sharepoint URL, and delegate the URL hierarchy to `shareplum.Site().List()`.  [`shareplum`](https://github.com/jasonrollins/shareplum) needs slightly better docs for practical use cases

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not actual solution for your problem and I would add just comment but it was too long so I will post as answer.

I can't replicate your issue, but by looking into source code of shareplum.py you can see why program throws the error. In line 196 of shareplum.py there is if clause (`if response.status_code == 200:`) which checks if the request to access your sharepoint url was successful (than it has status code 200) and if request failed (than it has some other status code)  than it throws exception  (Can't get User Info List). If you want to find out more about your problem go to your shareplum.py file ("C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\shareplum\shareplum.py") and add this line `print('{} {} Error: {} for url: {}'.format(response.status_code, 'Client'*(400 <= response.status_code < 500) + 'Server'*(500 <= response.status_code < 600), response.reason, response.url))` before line 207 ('raise Exception("Can't get User Info List")'). Then your shareplum.py should look like this:

```
# Parse Response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        envelope = etree.fromstring(response.text.encode('utf-8'))
        listitems = envelope[0][0][0][0][0]
        data = []  
        for row in listitems:
            # Strip the 'ows_' from the beginning with key[4:]
            data.append({key[4:]: value for (key, value) in row.items() if key[4:]})

        return {'py': {i['ImnName']: i['ID']+';#'+i['ImnName'] for i in data},
                'sp': {i['ID']+';#'+i['ImnName'] : i['ImnName'] for i in data}}
    else:
        print('{} {} Error: {} for url: {}'.format(response.status_code, 'Client'*(400 <= response.status_code < 500) + 'Server'*(500 <= response.status_code < 600), response.reason, response.url))
        raise Exception("Can't get User Info List")
```

Now just run your program again and it should print out why it isn't working.
I know it is best not to change files in Python modules, but if you know what you change then there is no problem so when you are finished just delete the added line.

Also when you find out status code you can search it online, just type it in google or search on [List_of_HTTP_status_codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).