# How to save a Sharepoint list as a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to save a sharepoint list as an excel/ csv file. To do so, I have followed following two SO links,

[Get SharePoint List with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903036/get-sharepoint-list-with-python/59937941#59937941)

[SharePlum error : "Can't get User Info List"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568823/shareplum-error-cant-get-user-info-list/45976417#45976417)

My code look like this,

```
import pandas as pd
from shareplum import Site 
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

cred = HttpNtlmAuth("email_id", "password")
site = Site('https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/analyticsandml', auth=cred)

sp_list = site.List('Client Office List') # this creates SharePlum object
data = sp_list.GetListItems('All Items') # this will retrieve all items from list

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data[0:])
data_df.to_excel("data.xlsx")

print("Content of share point list is saved in a file.")
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
shareplum.errors.ShareplumRequestError: Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/analyticsandml/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

Please help me with this.

**Note:** @Lee_MSFT on running your version of code, I get the error snapshot of which is below,
[image]

**Traceback:**
After using the shareplum based code, I get the following error,
[image]

**My views:** Shareplum based solution works when you use office365 with no other added layer of security like SecureAuth. If MFA is enabled, like in my case, it will give you invalid credentials error.

Comment: `Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url` <<-- This is a permission issue wherein the company server is preventing you from accessing it's resources. Try adding a `user-agent` as shown in this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden) and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The error is, TypeError: Site() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'. Also tried it with GetListItems() with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample demo to use [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/) to get SharePoint list data and output as excel.

```
import json
import pandas
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.client_request import ClientRequest
from office365.runtime.utilities.request_options import RequestOptions

url="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/"
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "password"):
  request = ClientRequest(ctx_auth)
  options = RequestOptions("{0}/sites/lee/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=ID,Title,ProjectType".format(url))
  options.set_header('Accept', 'application/json; odata=minimalmetadata')
  options.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  data = request.execute_request_direct(options)
  s = json.loads(data.content)
  data=s['value']
  pandas.read_json(json.dumps(data)).to_excel("output.xlsx")
  print("output")

else:
  print (ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

Update:

Tried [SharePlum](https://pypi.org/project/SharePlum/) in python 3.8.

```
import json
import pandas
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365

authcookie = Office365('https://xxx.sharepoint.com', username='user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/', authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('ListA')
data = sp_list.GetListItems('All Items')
pandas.read_json(json.dumps(data)).to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Debug screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. On running your version of code, I get an error snapshot of which is included in the question itself. Please let me know that how I can approach now.

Comment: What's your python version? "Python 2.7 & 3.4–3.6 are supported" based on the project description.

Comment: Python 3.8.1 64-bit (VS Code). Oh, so is it like I need to downgrade to Python 3.6?

Comment: Again, there's a problem, wanted to know that employee's user credentials should work fine or not? Traceback is included in the question. Eagerly waiting for your opinion.

Comment: Attached my debug screenshot, confirm whether you enabled MFA for your account.

Comment: Exception has occurred: Exception
('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.')
That's the error I am getting during debug, My company uses SecureAuth Authenticate. Whether this thing is creating a problem. I don't think that MFA is enabled (I have checked it from azure portal)

Comment: It should be related to SecureAuth, my test talent didn't integrate it.

Comment: I have also gone through some Microsoft docs, you are right! It is related to SecureAuth. Really interesting. So, is that mean, I cann't access file from sharepoint because of that, or do you have some workaround?